# Can't boot into any installed OS on 3 different SSD, after installing new OS on one SSD. Grub2 Error

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, ssd

Is it better to disconnect any SSD with an OS before installing a new OS on another SSD and then reconnect everything after ...or... keep everything connected and just install the new OS?  I seem to have done both in the past and I get a grub issue no matter what.

I looked at various suggestions and still haven't found a solution after 4 days of trying.
I've tried Boot Repair and System Rescue without success. I've typing in different commands into 2 different Grub2 error screens that I get = Grub Rescue and File/System not found. Said Linux kernal not found, but couldn't figure out how to resolve that.

In my BIOS, I set the WINDOWS 10 drive to boot 1st, and I'm able to get in there, or a USB, if I set that to boot 1st. but not other installed OS's.

My goal is to have one Ubuntu and one Windows that I use daily on different SSD's. Using a 3rd SSD, that will be where I experiment/install another OS sometimes. Grub seems to often give me problems when I try to use more than 2 OS's.

Here's my Boor Repair (Failed to Resolve) Report:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/GNnKzVzpw9/

Help? Suggestions?
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Looks like newer UEFI hardware but most installs in BIOS/MBR configuration. But have an ESP - efi system partition in sda1. Generally best not to mix BIOS & UEFI, but with multiple drives you technically can, but have to boot from UEFI menu, not grub. Grub can only boot other installs in same boot mode. Best to have each installs boot loader in MBR of drive its installed into. And with LVM and zfs may need extra drivers in other installs to see LVM or zfs. With multiple drives only use Boot-Repair's advanced mode and since old BIOS installs only boot in BIOS mode.